# Differences from SuperUser

Tags: discussion

Unfortunately a lot of questions here are about Hardware **support** as well as shopping. These questions belong on SuperUser. How do we prevent users from asking questions? How can we as a whole improve on this situation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm an SU mod. And well, I suggest that the best way to deal with this is the *same way* we would deal with questions that belong on SR or HW - close em. Keep closing em.

If its a great and glorious question that causes the heavens to open up and have a single sunbeam shine down on how awesome it is, vote or flag to migrate. If its a horrible question, don't bother, we'll kick it back.

As a *SR* mod, and having been through the process of helping bootstrap a new site, closures are an *essential* part of setting the scope of the site. Sometimes you got to set an example.

Comment: As a NE mod (pro tem and current) where we also get many questions that belong on SU, you can't stop users from asking them. I agree that you just have to keep closing them (and closing them and closing them and closing them and ...). Let me also throw in that you can vote/flag to migrate even a mediocre question where users have already provided good answers that deserve to be preserved.

Answer (score 8):

We really can't *prevent* them from asking them. Some (a lot of) people simply don't read the rules. What we can do, though, is **close the bad ones and migrate the good ones** to Super User (if you think it isn't crap, and won't be closed by SU, flag it with a custom flag and ask us to migrate it. We probably will).

I'm not terribly *happy* about so many of our questions being closed, but I think that it's just going to be a battle this site fights forever. SR fights the same battle to a lesser extent.